# Why does the First World War (WW I) play such a minor role today compared to Second World War (WW II)?

Tags: world-war-two, 20th-century, world-war-one, education, media

In my experience, in Central Europe, people are more aware of the Second World War, than the First World War. This seems to be the case in other European an American regions, too.

Do others also see this emphasis and awareness of WW2 over WW1?

How does knowledge of WW1 illuminate and explain current events?

How does understanding WW1 compare to understanding WW2, in terms of understanding current events and issues likely to arise?

Some points about WW1's importance:

- It happened exactly 100 years ago
- Many modern European (Italy, Great Britain, Austria, Hungary, France) were physically and politically shaped by it.
- It brought us modern warfare like tanks, airplanes, submarines
- It gave the USA the status of a worlds superpower
- It gave birth to important nations like Soviet Union and Turkey
- It marked the beginning of the end of world-wide Colonialism and and the end of Absolutism

A related, but perhaps separate question: How have the two wars been treated in popular films and literature? What are some of the better treatments and when were they made?

Comment: One short answer - there are a lot of people still alive today who served in (and remember) WWII but no veterans remain from WWI

Comment: Interest in WWI is currently undergoing a bit of a resurgence due to the 100 year anniversary. You might be interested in the YouTube channel [The Great War](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheGreatWar).

Comment: "*It was a real World War in contrary to WW II which was a series of local conflicts*" that's a pretty extraordinary claim. Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @Schwern Exactly. In fact, *series of local conflicts* applies more to WWI than WWII because of the developments in the Balkans.

Comment: I think this question can be salvaged. Instead of asking why there isn't more interest in WWI (asking our opinions of why "people" do something), it could instead ask what historical impact WWI has had on the 21st century that wasn't overlaid by WWII. Basically, what understanding of the 21st century can we gain from studying WWI that we cannot from just studying WWII? For example, the current map of the Middle East traces back to WWI.

Comment: Each and any of the points you expose is wrong; except for the one that states that it happened 100 years ago. And even that is a negative point, since obviously it is easier to see the effects in the present of more recent events that from older events (we can discuss the effects of, say, Vietnam War in the current day situation, but it would be senseless to discuss, say, the effects of the Battle of Alesia).

Comment: There is also the point that World War I was, in comparison, rather "uneventful" if one may use such words for the death of millions. Yes, there were tanks, and aircraft, and submarines, but in the end it was a rather static affair that does not attract casual interest the way that World War II does -- with its huge gains and losses, iconic weaponry (from rifles to planes to tanks to ships), and its huge number of "events", as opposed to the "two lines of trenches, artillery, perhaps gas, over the top, fall back, repeat" that was World War I.

Comment: @DevSolar That's only the Western Front. The very dynamic Eastern, African, and Middle Eastern fronts are all too often ignored, it was, after all, a World War.

Comment: @davidjwest I met one when I was a child - he served from 1914 all the way through

Answer (score 6):

World War II was in many respects a "continuation" war of World War I, from which there were a lot of "unfinished" business. World War II brought "closure" to many of these things. Consider the following:

1, Yes, tanks planes, submarines, and other weapons were developed during World War I,but it wasn't until World War II that people realized how destructive they were. One scientific idea, atomic theory already existed by World War I, but no one knew until World War II where it would lead.

2. World War I began the destruction of "European" empires (mainly Austria-Hungary and the Ottoman Empire), but it wasn't until World War II that *global* empires were dismantled, and countries like India became fully independent.
3. The League of Nations formed after World War I did not prevent a second world war. But the United Nations formed after World War II kept conflicts "local."

Comment: +1 because you elaborated my first point with more precision.

Comment: World War II actually built new empires (US western block and Soviet eastern block), while the Great War just destroyed old empires (except Germany, which was only slightly reduced in size and power, but kept as-it, much unfortunately).

Answer (score 4):

This is only an extended comment.

One (possibly unsatisfactory) reason is that WWII happened *after* WWI, and so the interwar period is *now* seen as a period of 20 years that led to an even greater conflict. Had WWII not happened, WWI would have been seen as a watershed event, one that led to the fall of Four great empires (Russia, Austria-Hungary, Germany and Ottoman).

Another interesting point is that, WWI is still seen in the Eastern Europe as the fire that gave birth to new nations, and revived old (like Poland). So it also largely depends on who you ask.